# How can I get the subway/bus distance between two locations in the NYC area?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I was able to query Google directions api for the driving distance between two points but they don't expose a way to get the distance or directions for the subway.  Is there a good api out there that does this?

Answer (score 1):

HopStop has a free API: http://www.hopstop.com/freeapi/
Haven't tried it myself yet thought.